# Convert date format to string in Pandas

Tags: pandas, date

For one date column, which has `na` values, with format `2019/1/1`, how could I convert it to `string` column with format `2019-01-01`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df["date"],errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').replace('NaT','')
```

Comment: works perfectly. thank you. one more question, in my code, `df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)` is not necessary, right?

Comment: @ahbon - `regex=True` is used if need repalce by subtrings, so here not.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach:

```
import pandas as pd

#Generate DF with date colums
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"date": ["2019/01/01", "2019/01/02", None, "2019/01/04", "2019/01/05", "2019/01/06"]})

#Convert it to datetime and immediately turn it back into desired string format.
df["date_new"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").replace("NaT", "")
```

Note that this approach eliminates the need for explicit error handling. This is the result:

```
         date    date_new
0  2019/01/01  2019-01-01
1  2019/01/02  2019-01-02
2        None            
3  2019/01/04  2019-01-04
4  2019/01/05  2019-01-05
5  2019/01/06  2019-01-06
```

Comment: Thank you, please note it’s necessary to replace NaT with empty for my case.

Answer (score 0):

This my solution so far, welcome to contribute precise and better solutions. Thanks.

```
# df = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors='coerce')     #Convert to date format
df['date'] = df["date"].dt.date     #filter and ignore hour, minute and second
df['date'] = df['date'].fillna("")     #fill na with empty
df['date'] = df["date"].astype(str)      #convert date to string
```